# Token Swapping on Raydium for Solana - Third-Party Router or Alternative DEX?

Tags: rust, smartcontracts, solana

I programmed a Solidity smart contract to automatically swap tokens on both Ethereum and Binance Smart Chain. Recently, I started developing something similar on Solana using Rust. I previously used the well-documented Uniswap RouterV2, but I can't find anything similar for Raydium on Solana.  Do I need a third-party router to achieve this on Raydium, or should I consider using another DEX, or is it simply not possible on Solana?

Raydium SDK, but the URL on the GitHub is deprecated and there are a lot of issues considering this, but noone ever replied.
Orderbook V2 is also utilized by Raydium afaik but there is no real documentation.